# Data Stitching Join/Merge - Oracle Vs Java based technique

Tags: java, oracle, join, dataset

Currently I am facing a distinct issue, where I receive data from a webservice call, same need to be loaded into Oracle Table.

Scenario:
- I have a very huge table with 500 columns - all columns mandatory, and no choice to split table.
- Dataset is 50m records, which I am trying to export from source system - and its continuously increasing
- At a time I receive 50 column data by firing request to webservice (at source system), hence I need to submit 10 request of 50 column each for getting full record.
- Also at a time I can only receive 100000 (1 lac) records in one request for specific set of columns.

Now, to import same data into Oracle DB at destination system I have following two choices:
1. First export data on temporary tables of 50 columns each and then run join for all of them to create final table with all 500 columns
2. Fire 10 parallel request of 50 columns each and stitch data on my java program and then send insert query with all 500 columns

Here I would like to know, which technique works out better, to go with Oracle based table join or apply stitching on java side by using Primary Key column?

As the data set is very huge, I am purely looking on performance aspect. Also any more optimized ways to solve same problem?

Comment: If database supports programmable functions (Procedures ?) , use those with some temporary tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From performance point of view the Oracle based solution would clearly win. From implementation point of view (aiming for a clear and simple solution) Oracle tables win again. Here is why:

- **Architecture point of view**: Combining the data in your app will make your app stateful. From a simple stateless (receive-save-forget) application you would turn it into a complex state-aware (save-look for joint records-did not find anything-store-wait-look again-etc). This is much harder to develop, maintain or debug.
- **Performance point of view**: Saving data into multiple tables and later combining them into one (either by views or stored procedures or simple selects) is something Oracle is designed for. Immense amount of development time was spent on optimizing these basic features. Whatever you would come up with to implement the same features (even though you are aware of some specifics) would likely performe worse.

So overall I would strongly suggest Option #1, leave it for Oracle to do the hard part. Depending on how you want to use this data after the import (almost real-time / once in a while / after extra filtering applied) you can choose how you construct the final records by using one of these:

- stored procedures
- Oracle jobs
- views.

Comment: I'm not so sure Oracle is a clear performance winner here, since the Java program could consume the web service (getting 100,000 records of 50 columns) and call Oracle to insert (for the 1st set of columns) or update (for the subsequent sets) directly into the end table.  Also, consuming web service via Java code is a little easier.  No upvote or downvote here -- I'd still be inclined to do as much in Oracle as I could, but I'm not sure it's a slam dunk.

Comment: *"consuming web service via Java code is a little easier"* - to be honest it never even occured to me that the poster would try to actually consume the webservice from Oracle... I mean I have seen jars added to the an Oracle database, but that is really a last resort. My proposed solution was just a simple program saving the data and leave the joining for some DB feature.

Comment: Something has to get the data from the web service and move it to Oracle.  If that "something" is Java, then it may be easier / faster to just have that Java put the results into the final table.